# The info about who deleted what and when is gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers

I can only reproduce this at EL&U because I don't have 10K elsewhere. It could be a problem elsewhere.

Yesterday a deleted answer had a little note saying who deleted it and when:

[image: answer with deleter info]

Today that same answer does not have that information:

[image: answer without deleter info]

[Link to the particular answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3071/3559)

This is happening on both meta and main EL&U.

Should I be able to see who deleted something and when?

Comment: I see this on SO as well ([example question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263937/which-is-the-most-popular-net-unit-testing-framework)). Possibly by design?

Comment: Yes, since you have over 10K you should be able to see who deleted something and when. Smells like a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hm? Your example was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: Good to know, @YannisRizos. I thought I was losing it!

Comment: @YannisRizos: But *I don't see the reason listed anymore*. If *you* do, then that's another datapoint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see the deleted question (need to get 9163 moar rep for that, brb), but I see it listed as "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." in the 404 page.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Right, but I, as a 10K user, don't see a reason listed. A [deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236040) on the other hand *does* have the reason listed.

Comment: Confirmed here on meta as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145978/152859 [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KwwK8.png)

Comment: Interesting, so we can find answers (deleted over a day ago) that do have the reason included, and answers where the reason has gone.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/75313/revisions) shows it's a self delete. The information is there, just not displayed properly?

Comment: I see the same behaviour on [su] as well. Posts deleted by me/other mods don't seem to be showing who deleted it

Comment: @Yannis indeed, looks like design glitch not data problem.

Comment: I confirm on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: I started to notice this last night.  On one occasion, refreshing the page filled in the delete info, but not in others.  Very strange.  [Here is an SO example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7aFvo.png) from 5 seconds ago showing that it is not happening in that instance.

Comment: Site mods and 10k ELU users go to the [ELU recently deleted list](http://english.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=) and notice those all show the problem of not having a delete reason or time displayed when you click through to them.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. As moderator on Drupal Answers, I see who deleted a question, but not an answer. This is pretty not consistent. Why could I see who deleted a question, but not an answer?

Comment: @MonicaCellio What I’ve been able to do in that case is to “stealth-edit” the deleted post, adding something like `<!-- stealth edit to try trigger delete history showing up -->`, and then you can see the history via the edit link.  But it still doesn’t force an explanation in the normal view. Maybe this is a  bug introduced by a new build recently going live, since it seems to be occurring across many SE sites.

Comment: @tchrist There is no need to do that: The revision page uses http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/18941/revisions as URL. The answer given for this answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146046/140449) has http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/146046/revisions as revision page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.