# Missing parenthesis after the number of deleting votes

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I see a question that has been voted to be deleted, I read "delete (1" instead of "delete (1)" I was used to read before.

This happens on Meta Stack Overflow, and other sites.

> [image: Meta Stack Overflow]

> [image: English Language & Usage]

I checked the HTML output, and effectively the parenthesis is missing. It is not hidden by two HTML elements that are overlapping each other.

It doesn't happen with the "close" link, for which the closing parenthesis is present.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Confirmed that this occur across multiple SE sites, and is not just `(1`, but includes other vote counts, too, such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963019/how-to-learn-proper-c) where it shows `(8` as of this writing.  I wonder whether this isn’t somehow related to [this new deletion bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145976/the-info-about-who-deleted-what-and-when-is-gone). **Perhaps a recent build going live with a bug in the delete code, *starting about yesterday?***

Comment: Heh, sounds like a `(@(..)` mistake.

Comment: There's also a suspicious amount of [extra whitespace](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ7i9.png) that shouldn't be there either.

Comment: @TimStone Shut up! I am working on an MVC/Razor site right now, and just kicked myself over one of those... ;)

Comment: @TimStone Yes, there is definitively extra space around the "delete" link. I can see it in this very question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.