# Delete button is a little wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design

The "delete" button on questions with no present delete votes is a little wide:

[image: Question buttons]

(Blame the whitespace!)

Comment: It's [already been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146028/missing-parenthesis-after-the-number-of-deleting-votes), but possibly not deployed yet to SO.  Look at the menu bar in this question for comparison (it was too wide here earlier also).

Comment: and now we will have someone to complain _"the other links are too close to the delete link, there should be some extra white-space"_

Comment: +1 for eagle eye notice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, why not.​​​​​​​​​​​​