# Missing word in delete link tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, vote-to-delete, tooltips

The word "delete" is missing from the tooltip shown when you mouse over the delete link.  As a result, the tooltip reads "vote to  this post" (notice the extra space):

[image: Missing word in delete link tooltip]

Firefox 15 on Windows 7.  Can someone look into this?

Comment: I see the same on Mac, both on Firefox 15 and on Chrome 21.

Comment: I remember 2 days ago they had a [white-space problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146067/179635) with the delete link, my only theory is that it is getting stronger and smarter, if we don't stop it while we can, God knows what might hapP$YJ.. HEPL PLX, calL tH Police

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

It should say "vote to **remove** this post", actually, not delete. This bug was introduced in a recent cleanup of the code that renders post menus.