# Bug in nonaccepted answers sorting higher than the accepted answer

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted)

I’ve just noticed [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843878/django-social-auth-how-to-get-the-profile-pic-of-facebook-and-save-it-in-media/12285585#12285585) where a non-accepted answer sorting higher than the accepted one:

[image]

I didn’t think that could ever happen. Is this a new bug related to a fresh build going live within the last 24 hours, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145976/the-info-about-who-deleted-what-and-when-is-gone?lq=1) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146028/missing-parenthesis-after-the-number-of-deleting-votes) may also be? There are too many strange things (read: *new bugs*) going on today not to wonder whether there’s some common cause of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers posted and accepted by the OP themselves do not qualify to be auto-bumped to the top of the answers and instead get sorted as normal.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the right answer.